# Webpack uses wrong path to import bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, code-splitting

so I'm having a problem with webpack codesplitting. It creates bundles correctly but then everything is getting messed up when it sends xhr request for the bundle. Only the index route works correctly 'cause it's just a `/` but it actually uses client side route as path to bundle. So using the example below it goes with the path `localhost:3000/dir/something/0.bundle.js` instead of `localhost:3000/0.bundle.js`. I'm new to webpack, is there a way to make it use the `/` route every time?

**pseudo markup**

```html
<Link to="/dir/something/else"/>

<!-- <App/>  -->

  <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/dir/:param1/:param2">
                        <Bar/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Foo/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

I'm using `@loadable/component` so each component is imported with a `loadable(()=>import('path/to/component'))`

**webpack.config.js**

```js
  {
    mode,
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x)?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 5000
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
      hot: true
    },
    plugins: [new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html'
    })],
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json']
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have u tried setting `publicPath` in webpack config ? if not try that.. read webpack doc for more info

Comment: @Panther Yes! Thank you, I had no idea what to look for.